# Large base64 string data file

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, base64, blob

What is the best and most efficient way to upload large video, audio or pdf file to my laravel backend using javascript vuejs to be precise?.

I'm currently trying to convert the file to base64 but the issue that i am having is that the string becomes very long and i get a 413 payload too large error.

Comment: Could you send it in smaller chunks?

Comment: how will i do that...can you assist me..

Comment: Maybe. Can you show us what your current solution looks like where you are getting the 413 issue?

Comment: Base64 is always larger than the original file. It is not compression but just encoding (with overhead)

Comment: Just use FormData and `multipart/form-data`. As mentioned, base64 encoding will increase the size of the request content.

Comment: uploadVideo(e, fileType, index, indexes){ 
   if(fileType === 'audio'){
 let reader = new FileReader();
 let file = e.target.files[0];
 reader.onload = (event) => {

         for(let i = 0; i < this.product.videoContent.length; i++){
                          this.product.videoContent[index].videoEpisode[indexes].videoFile = event.target.result;
                              }
                                 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

}

i am looping through an array within array...thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the reply @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: [Here's a complete example of a file CRUD app in laravel and vue from Feb 2018.](https://codeburst.io/upload-and-manage-files-with-laravel-and-vue-915378c8b2a4) The code is on github. Maybe you can borrow the file upload parts.

Comment: thanks @ourmandave...it was really helpful